# Программное изменение цвета картинки

Tags: java, android, imageview

В первой активити программно устанавливаю цвет картинки.

```
Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.pic, null);
drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Далее с помощью интентов вызываю вторую активити с этой же картинкой,но без всяких фильтров.Так получаю цвет картинки как с первой активити, а не как она идет по умолчанию.

> Как мне сделать так что бы цвет у картинки менялся только в первой
>   активити, а не во всех?Просто не горю желанием держать по пять одинаковых картинок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Drawable drawable= DrawableCompat.wrap(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.pic,null)).mutate();
drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, а то гугл ничего не дал, а я начал такую ерунду городить.